# Typescript npm publish with subpath exports

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, npm-publish

I am trying to create a npm package with a bit uncommon use case. I have two typescript files `error.ts` and `filehandle.ts`. These modules have their classes. After package is published, I want to import specific modules separately.
Currently, I have imported all in one.

```
import {ErrorClassA, ErrorClassB, Reader, Writer } from 'package';
```

Since errors and file handles are not similar modules, I want to import like below.

```js
import { ErrorClassA, ErrorClassB } from 'package/error'
import { Reader, Writer } from 'package/filehandle'
```

error and filehandles are given beow.

error.ts

```js
export class ErrorClassA {
   ....
}

export class ErrorClassB {
   ....
}
```

filehandle.ts

```js
export class Reader {
}
```

Comment: A common pattern I've seen and has used so far is to use the index.ts on the root level - this will import and then name export all the classess/methods. You can then create index.ts files on each individual sub modules and default export the classes/methods from there.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/packages/material-ui/src - is a pretty neat example of how they organized the export

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76236503/not-able-to-get-typescript-definitions-working-when-using-subpath-exports/76236761#76236761